# Not able to access the directory created in HDFS after all the Hadoop deamons are stopped and restarted again

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop i have a couple of problem and yet i am not able to find any solution my issue goes as below:

```
**Created a directory on HDFS using below command:
 --bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /user/abhijit/apple_poc
**Checking if my directory has been created:
 --bin/hadoop fs -ls
 --(output)-->drwxr-xr-x   - abhijit supergroup          0 2013-07-11 11:09 /user/abhijit/apple_poc
**Stopping all hadoop daemons:
 --bin/stop-all.sh 
**Restarting all the daemons again:
 --bin/start-all.sh 
**Again checking if my directory on HDFS created above is present or not:
 --bin/hadoop fs -ls
 --(output):
 2013-07-11 11:37:57.304 java[3457:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
 13/07/11 11:37:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:37:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:38:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:38:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:38:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:38:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:38:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:38:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:38:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 13/07/11 11:38:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
 Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Please clarify..

1. I am really not sure what i am doing wronge,or is there anything to change in property file?
2. HDFS default directory storage is /user//,should i change this default directory so that my problem is solved?
3. Every time i have to format the namenode to come out of this problem but after formating my directory created above is lost.

Please let me know what is the issue behind this..
Much appreciated for your help.

Thanks,
Abhijit

Answer (score 2):

This error occur because of multiple reason, I have been playing around with hadoop. Got this issue multiple times and cause was different

1. if main nodes are not running -> check the logs
2. if proper ip is not mentioned in host file[after setting hostname, provides its ip in hosts file so that other nodes can access it]